# How to parse the below xml file in php?

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I am working on the following xml file and can't get the namespaces to work in PHP using the SimpleXmlElement or simplexml_load_file

How would I get the seperate cac:InvoiceLine lines parsed as these I need to add into a database as records per invoiceline.

I can see the different namespace when using the getNamespaces() but still I don't get them to split out right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?><SelfBilledInvoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SelfBilledInvoice-2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CoreComponentParameters-2" xmlns:stat="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:DocumentStatusCode-1.0" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:draft:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2">
  <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
  <cbc:ID>CBF-123</cbc:ID>
  <cbc:CopyIndicator>false</cbc:CopyIndicator>
  <cbc:IssueDate>2016-07-05</cbc:IssueDate>
  <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>D</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
  <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>EUR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
  <cbc:LineCountNumeric>1</cbc:LineCountNumeric>
  <cac:BillingReference>
    <cac:SelfBilledInvoiceDocumentReference>
      <cbc:ID>112.pdf</cbc:ID>
    </cac:SelfBilledInvoiceDocumentReference>
  </cac:BillingReference>
  <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:Party>
      <cac:PartyIdentification>
        <cbc:ID>30276460</cbc:ID>
      </cac:PartyIdentification>
      <cac:PartyName>
        <cbc:Name>CB</cbc:Name>
      </cac:PartyName>
      <cac:PostalAddress>
        <cbc:Postbox>123</cbc:Postbox>
        <cbc:CityName>City</cbc:CityName>
        <cbc:PostalZone>zipcode</cbc:PostalZone>
        <cac:Country>
          <cbc:IdentificationCode>NL</cbc:IdentificationCode>
          <cbc:Name>Nederland</cbc:Name>
        </cac:Country>
      </cac:PostalAddress>
      <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
        <cbc:CompanyID>NL123</cbc:CompanyID>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:Name>NL VAT</cbc:Name>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
    </cac:Party>
    <cac:AccountingContact>
      <cbc:Telephone>0111-1118</cbc:Telephone>
      <cbc:Telefax>0111-11118</cbc:Telefax>
    </cac:AccountingContact>
  </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
  <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:Party>
      <cac:PartyIdentification>
        <cbc:ID>9573703</cbc:ID>
      </cac:PartyIdentification>
      <cac:PartyName>
        <cbc:Name>A&E</cbc:Name>
      </cac:PartyName>
      <cac:PostalAddress>
        <cbc:StreetName>Street 33</cbc:StreetName>
        <cbc:InhouseMail>205</cbc:InhouseMail>
        <cbc:CityName>City</cbc:CityName>
        <cbc:PostalZone>zone</cbc:PostalZone>
        <cac:Country>
          <cbc:IdentificationCode>NL</cbc:IdentificationCode>
          <cbc:Name>Nederland</cbc:Name>
        </cac:Country>
      </cac:PostalAddress>
      <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
        <cbc:CompanyID>NL222</cbc:CompanyID>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:Name>NL VAT</cbc:Name>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
    </cac:Party>
  </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
  <cac:PaymentMeans>
    <cbc:PaymentMeansCode>AO</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
    <cbc:PaymentDueDate>2016-09-15</cbc:PaymentDueDate>
    <cbc:InstructionNote>Totaal af te dragen omzet</cbc:InstructionNote>
    <cac:PayerFinancialAccount>
      <cbc:ID>NL11RAB11111111</cbc:ID>
      <cac:FinancialInstitutionBranch>
        <cbc:ID>RABONL1U</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Name>Rabobank</cbc:Name>
      </cac:FinancialInstitutionBranch>
    </cac:PayerFinancialAccount>
  </cac:PaymentMeans>
  <cac:TaxTotal>
    <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.66</cbc:TaxAmount>
    <cac:TaxSubtotal>
      <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">10.94</cbc:TaxableAmount>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.66</cbc:TaxAmount>
      <cbc:Percent>6</cbc:Percent>
      <cac:TaxCategory>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:Name>NL VAT</cbc:Name>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:TaxCategory>
    </cac:TaxSubtotal>
  </cac:TaxTotal>
  <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="EUR">10.94</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
    <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="EUR">11.60</cbc:PayableAmount>
  </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>79469458</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">10.94</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cac:OrderLineReference>
      <cbc:LineID>82947243</cbc:LineID>
    </cac:OrderLineReference>
    <cac:AllowanceCharge>
      <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
      <cbc:MultiplierFactorNumeric>0.42</cbc:MultiplierFactorNumeric>
      <cbc:Amount currencyID="EUR">7.92</cbc:Amount>
    </cac:AllowanceCharge>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.66</cbc:TaxAmount>
      <cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">10.94</cbc:TaxableAmount>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.66</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cbc:Percent>6</cbc:Percent>
        <cbc:PerUnitAmount currencyID="EUR">18.86</cbc:PerUnitAmount>
        <cac:TaxCategory>
          <cac:TaxScheme>
            <cbc:Name>NL VAT</cbc:Name>
          </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:TaxCategory>
      </cac:TaxSubtotal>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:Item>
      <cbc:Description>TITLE</cbc:Description>
      <cac:StandardItemIdentification>
        <cbc:ID>9789079995318</cbc:ID>
      </cac:StandardItemIdentification>
      <cac:AdditionalItemProperty>
        <cbc:Name>Afnemer</cbc:Name>
        <cbc:Value>ABC</cbc:Value>
      </cac:AdditionalItemProperty>
    </cac:Item>
    <cac:Price>
      <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">19.99</cbc:PriceAmount>
    </cac:Price>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
</SelfBilledInvoice>
```

This is not a duplicate of the general xml parsing code as this has a number of namespace that prevent the general code to work. The part i don't get in is splitting the namespaces like cac, cbc etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: What did you for solving this problem ? Display your code then someone will give you the solution.

Comment: <?php
$fn = "9573703.xml";

$data = new SimpleXmlElement($fn,null,true);

$namespaces = $data->getNamespaces(true);


foreach($data->children($namespaces['cac']) as $entry) {

 $eID = $entry->ID ;

 echo $entry." ".$eID."<br>";
}

?>

Comment: Any tips or pointers?

Comment: thanks for the tips.........trying this out for the first time and no response at all that i can do something with... nice....

Comment: Can you check xml again, what is the data on line number 49 in xml?

Comment: As I can see on line no 49  `<cbc:Name>A&E</cbc:Name>` data, because `&` is a reserved character in XML that means "an XML entity begins here".